# In PBKDF2 is INT (i) signed?

Tags: security, sha, hmac, integer-overflow, pbkdf2

Page 11 of RFC 2898 states that for U_1 = PRF (P, S || INT (i)), INT (i) is a four-octet encoding of the integer i, most significant octet first.

Does that mean that i is a signed value and if so what happens on overflow?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing says that it would be signed.  The fact that `dkLen` is capped at `(2^32 - 1) * hLen` suggests that it's an unsigned integer, and that it cannot roll over from `0xFFFFFFFF` (2^32 - 1) to `0x00000000`.

Of course, PBKDF2(MD5) wouldn't hit 2^31 until you've asked for 34,359,738,368 bytes.  That's an awful lot of bytes.

- SHA-1: 42,949,672,960
- SHA-2-256 / SHA-3-256: 68,719,476,736
- SHA-2-384 / SHA-3-384: 103,079,215,104
- SHA-2-512 / SHA-3-512: 137,438,953,472

Since the .NET implementation (in Rfc2898DeriveBytes) is an iterative stream it could be polled for 32GB via a (long) series of calls.  Most platforms expose PBKDF2 as a one-shot, so you'd need to give them a memory range of 32GB (or more) to identify if they had an error that far out.  So even if most platforms get the sign bit wrong... it doesn't really matter.

PBKDF2 is a KDF (key derivation function), so used for deriving keys.  AES-256 is 32 bytes, or 48 if you use the same PBKDF2 to generate an IV (which you really shouldn't).  Generating a private key for the ECC curve with a [34,093 digit prime](http://primes.utm.edu/top20/page.php?id=27) is (if I did my math right) 14,157 bytes.  Well below the 32GB mark.

Comment: 34,359,738,368 bits not bytes :) 

But doesn't i range from [1 .. l] where l = CEIL (dkLen / hLen) so it can still overflow if hLen = 1 for dkLen > 2^31 which is theoretically valid

I agree it's about as far as you can get from a practical use case

Comment: 2^31 is 2G, * 128bit (MD5) = 256Gbit, or 32GB. Yeah, an 8-bit PRF would hit the confusion zone at 2GB, but as @erickson suggested, it ends up not mattering anyways since you just add to the bit-pattern and neither division nor an inequality are involved.

Answer (score 0):

`i` ranges from 1 to `l = CEIL (dkLen / hLen)`, and `dkLen` and `hLen` are positive integers. Therefore, `i` is strictly positive.

You can, however, store `i` in a signed, 32-bit integer type without any special handling. If `i` rolls over (increments from `0x7FFFFFFF` to `0xF0000000`), it will continue to be encoded correctly, and continue to increment correctly. With two's complement encoding, bitwise results for addition, subtraction, and multiplication are the same as long as all values are treated as either signed or unsigned.